# StackAudio Twitter Feed

Tags: discussion, promotion

The Stack Exchange folks have created an automated Twitter feed for every Stack Exchange site.  The one for this site is [StackAudio](http://twitter.com/StackAudio).  Details are in [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/twitter-question-feeds-for-stack-exchange/).

Comment: have things changed?  is it no longer used?